# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent create() method shows foreign key exception but save() doesn't show any error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-5

Here is the situation:

I have two tables users and projects. Users table has one to many relation with projects table. When I try to insert data in projects table by using `Model::create()` method, it shows foreign key constraint error. But when I create an instance of Project model and set attribute and use `$modelObject->save()` method it works. Below is the code

**ProjectsController.php (Controller) (function: postStart()) -**

```
public function postStart(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->input();

    $project = Project::create(array(
        'title' => $input['title'],
        'main_category_id' => $input['category'],
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'slug' => Helper::slug($input['title']),
    ));

    $project['slug'] = Helper::slug($input['title'], $project->id);
    $project->save();

    return redirect('project/'.$project->slug.'/edit');
}
```

**Project.php (model)**

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'main_category_id', 'sub_category_id', 'title', 'slug', 'description', 'project_location', 'project_url', 'project_image', 'type', 'min_bid_amount'];

    public static $updatable = ['user_id' => "", 'main_category_id' => "", 'sub_category_id' => "", 'title' => "", 'slug' => "", 'description' => "", 'project_location' => "", 'project_url' => "", 'project_image' => "", 'type' => "", 'min_bid_amount' => ""];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

**And Here is the error**

> QueryException in Connection.php line 673: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kickstarter`.`projects`, CONSTRAINT `projects_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `projects` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2016-05-24 13:00:27, 2016-05-24 13:00:27))

But when I insert using `$modelObject->save()` method it works. I do not understand what is the problem. It would be very helpful if I found a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that you provided all needed information?
If you will check `create()` function, you will see:

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    $model = new static($attributes);

    $model->save();

    return $model;
}
```

So `create` method also use `save` method. You can see from your exception, that you don't set any value for fields. As result - your problem either in `$attributes` or in constructor in your class. Because `$attributes` seems like have values and fields are fillable - you need go further into constructor.
Also there is an error in relation

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id');
}
```

The method should return
`$this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id')` or `$this->belongsTo('User')`

**UPD:**

As we understand from commetns, constructor was re-implemented and as result - attributes assignment doesn't work. To fix this issue you need just call parent constructor method and add new logic, that you need:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    // some additional code
}
```

Comment: Hello @f0rtis, thanks for the reply. I have corrected the relation but the error still persists. Even I am able to save data by manually assigning attributes to model class object and using $modelObject->save(). I just don't understand why Model::create() is not working in this function. But I am using Model::create() in other functions and it is working fine there.

Comment: @JitenderSingla as i said - are you sure that you don't reimplemented `__construct` of your class? Or maybe `fill` method or `setAttribute`? Maybe it was done in extended class

Comment: Hello @fortis, your assumption is right. I have used  `__construct`  in the model class to initialize some paths to public folder. Does it affect anything ?

Comment: @JitenderSingla, of course it affect, because `create` method doesn't work properly. I will update my answer, so please check it one more time.

Comment: Hello @fortis, I am gonna implement it today. Will let you know the result.

Comment: Hello @fortis, thanks a ton. I have implemented it and it worked. Thanks alot on this. But I also want to know why this happened, because in Laravel 4, I never faced this issue.

Comment: @JitenderSingla reason why it's happened - because you fully rewrite logic of parent class, but correct way was to improve logic. It's very large theme to explain, so i advise to read about OOP principles. In your case you need to pay attention on inheritance part.

Comment: Hello @fortis, you mean, it is simply using inheritance. Ok, I will study it further. Thanks a lot.